# More elegant <noscript> solution?

Tags: javascript, html, noscript

The [`<noscript>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp) can be used to display a message if the user has scripting turned off - but is there any way in which it can be used to contain a conditional (html) statement, or more complicated coding?

Edit: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear; I have nothing against the noscript tag itself - but was wondering about the upward limitations of its usage? As far as I have seen, its usage has been merely to tell people to turn scripting on. I'm thinking about potential in terms of accessibility.

Comment: The `<noscript>` tag can contain any HTML markup you want.

Comment: You can use CSS to set the display to none for the container element and then use javascript to set the display property to block/inline using javascript.

Comment: @Chandu why would you do that instead of just putting content in the `<noscript>` block?

Comment: @Pointy : Ah, but if you have let's say a javascript menu; would it be  bad design to have a backup pure CSS menu nested between noscript tags in the event that someone has scripting turned off (in the same way as one might have a backup stylesheet in the event that someone is using ie7)?

Comment: @Pointy Its just an alternative if OP really doesn't want to use noscript tag.

Comment: Why would you want the tag that is called when javascript is not available, to contain javascript if/else statements?  They would not run. You need to develop in javascript, and show / hide your containers based off the if / else.

Comment: @Duncan No that would be the opposite of "bad design", though if you've got a working pure CSS menu I don't know why you'd want a JavaScript menu also.

Comment: As a question about elegance, as per the heading, this question belongs to the “Not constructive” category. But the text of the question is different, making the question “Not a real question”, with inadequate concepts like “conditional (html) statements”. No description of the original problem (with `noscript` as assumed approach) has been given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with `<noscript>`? It can contain anything you'd want. From entire layouts, to `<style>` elements to a big fat warning message.

Obviously, you can't use JavaScript inside of it, but aside from that, you can do anything.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
<div id="removeIfJS">Sorry, but javascript is disabled</div>
<script>
 var sorry = document.getElementById("removeIfJS");
 sorry.parentNode.removeChild(sorry);
</script>
```

Comment: Is this really better than the no-code-needed simplicity of `<noscript>`?

Comment: @Pointy - This is just an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Stick to the noscript tag because it's the standard method to solve things. Search engines knows how to deal with it, screen readers know to deal with it and people that have turned javascript off will see a fancy warning/message (with some CSS).

BTW: You cannot do any fancy stuff if scripting is turned off as well.

In a noscript tag you can use all elements that are allowed directly in a body tag. See the link you provided for details.